# Opencart *Multistore with shared DB* and 1000 concurrent req/store VS "1000 Seperate Stores" with 1 concurrent request/store

Tags: opencart2.x, multisite, multistore

I'm planning to run a multistore using  open-cart with more than 1000 stores.

I realized that by using Multistore all the stores will be on a single database.

Another way is to install each store separately with separate DB.

Which one is better for about 1000 stores with 100 products in each store and 1 concurrent request/store ? "**Multistore with shared DB**" or "**seperate Stores with seperate databases**"?

If i had separate database for each store, a search query in each store was an easy query. But if all the stores have single shared database, is this simple search query as easy as before?

Comment: I think you might get a performance penalty. As 1000 stores and 100+ products for each store might hit your server.

Comment: @VedPandya I eddited my question. Assume that we had enough resorces. I need to know which one is better?

Comment: The real question is, how many concurrent requests do you expect? I.e. one request / shop could be the same as 1000 times more requests for a single shop. Would your DB / webserver support that? OTOH, if it's just for search, may be you need to consider using something else entirely (e.g. ons database as backup, index all products in ElasticSearch and serve search requests from there).

Comment: @Ashalynd I eddited my question. Assume 1 concurrent request/store. so the question is: which one is better? Multistore with single database with 1000 concurrent request or 1000 stores with 1000 separate database and 1 concurrent request per store

Comment: It's not an all or nothing. If you have lots of stores with little traffic, it makes sense to combine them into a single database with multi store. But for stores with heavy traffic, you need to scale out to multiple machines, and this is easier done with separate database instances.

Comment: @LieRyan we have lots of stores with little traffic.

Comment: You can always start with one DB and split it when you notice performance problems.